# Full screen background image with border

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

What I need (and failed) to do is website like in this picture:

Website need to be full screen and no scroll.
I'm not satisfied with results, because:

-when website is opened on vertical screens (smartphones) the bottom border is too big

-I also tried to make this background image to show fully top and bottom (I want to faces at top and bottom to be seen in full, not just partly), but I don't really know how to do it.

My CSS code:

```css
html
{

    background: #f36d32;
    width: 98%;
    height: 95.9%;
    padding: 1%;

}

    body
    {
    background: url(http://web-industry.eu/landing/img/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
```

Ok, the border problem is solved by @imGaurav with such a code:

```css
body {
  background: url('http://web-industry.eu/landing/img/bg.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: #f36d32 3px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

But I still can't figure out how to make both top and bottom faces to be visible.

Comment: can you share your code with us?

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry, here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/24rcLmsj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: url('http://web-industry.eu/landing/img/bg.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: #f36d32 3px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: He said "I want to faces at top and bottom to be seen in full, not just partly". Your code doesn't show full faces in all resolutions

Comment: Thank you, you partly solved my problem (with border). But as @Sylwek said I still want to both top and bottom faces to be fully visible.

Comment: if your are talking about the cutting faces of top and bottom that is in your image only  , you can not do anything with css .if you see your image faces are cut in it take a new image with full faces and apply above code on it that should work

Answer (score 0):

So you just want the full size image to scale with different with different screen sizes?

In your css on the image div try:

background-size: contain;

If that is not what you are after, here is a link to all the property values you can use and test out.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add below CSS to your HTML body

```
position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean somethink like that?

```
<div class="vertical-container">
    <div class="vertical-middle">
        <img src="http://www.susansolovic.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/instagram-logo-md-300x300.png">
    </div>
</div>


html,body {
    height: 100%;    
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.vertical-container {
    background-color: green;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.vertical-middle {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/org72bfb/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css to solve the problem. Reference [CSS-trick](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

```
html { 
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRKcX.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: No, he can't, because he asid "I want to faces at top and bottom to be seen in full, not just partly"